# iphone UITextField changes in a UITableView with a UIButton

Tags: iphone

[image: Screen shot]

here problem is that when i pressed first row Plus button it change value of second Qty.

i need to change particular Qty change as per row select.

i also given viewWithtag on textfield but can't work properly.

thanks in advance.

Comment: we are not able to see screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the tag for `UIButton` & `UITextField` as:

set Button tag as `[indexpath row]+1`
set Textfield tag as `([indexpath row]+1)* 10`

so there will be no mismatch of tags

When a button is pressed check the condition like this:

```
UITextField * textfield = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:([sender tag]+1)*10];
if([sender tag] == 1)
textfield.text = //value you want to set
```

Answer (score 0):

set tag of textfield equal to the [indexpath row].